# VBA Open workbook and assign it to variable error

Tags: vba

I'm writing macro that goes through the file and marks lines that match some conditions as OK. Everything works fine when launched from the file. The problem is that when I try to launch it from another workbook I keep getting this error "Run time error 1004: Select method or Range class failed" at line

Range("C2").Select

I think that the problem lies in assigning opened file to the variable mainFile. (I can browse for the file, it opens and I can enter the year I want then it crashes)
Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
    Sub sbVBA_To_Open_Workbook_FileDialog()

Dim strFileToOpen As Variant
Dim mainFile As Workbook

    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", MultiSelect:=False)

    If TypeName(strFileToOpen) = "String" Then
        Set mainFile = Workbooks.Open(strFileToOpen)
    Else
        MsgBox "No file selected."
        Exit Sub
    End If

'sub data works fine
Call data

With mainFile

'Everything below works fine when launched in the mainfile
Dim myYear As Date

myYear = InputBox("Choose year", "Choose year", 2018)

    Range("C2").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = "M" Then

        If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2) = "C" Then

                If Day(ActiveCell.Value) = 1 Then

                                If Year(ActiveCell.Value) = myYear Then

                                    If Month(ActiveCell.Value) & Year(ActiveCell.Value) = Month(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) & Year(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then

                                    '^Comparing years and months

                                        If DateSerial(Year(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value), Month(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value + 1), 0) = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
                                        ' ^End of month?

                                            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = "OK"
                                        Else
                                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = "NOK"
                                        End If

                                    Else
                                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = "NOK"
                                    End If

                                Else
                                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = "NOK"
                                End If

                Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = "NOK"
                End If
        Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = "NOK"
        End If
    Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = "NOK"
    End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: try add mainFile.activate

Comment: in order to `.select`, the wb to select from must be infront

Comment: including worksheet, before `.select`, bring the worksheet to the top window using `worksheet.activate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you open a workbook, it won’t automatically assume it’s the active workbook.

Please try the following code after the “With mainFile” row:

```
mainFile.Sheets([your desired sheet]).Activate
```

Then, before the range.select part, add activesheet:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(“C2”).Select
```

Comment: I've added mainFile.Sheets(2).Activate line. Now macro opens the file and goes to the second sheet. However it still crashes and the error remains the same

Comment: Voila! Thank you very much:)

Comment: You should always activate the sheet of your need, or reference it, otherwise the default assumed workbook is the workbook the macro runs from.

Comment: Thank you once again. I will remember that